# How do I pass object correctly to my vue component?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am recently learning Vue and I have read documentation about Vue [components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props). However, I still do not understand how I can pass data object to props and have it rendered in the component template.

Here is my jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/2930hn7g/402/)

Or see my code below.

```js
Vue.component('greeting', {
  template: `<h1>{{index}}</h1>`,
  props: ['persons']
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    persons: {
      'Mike': 'Software Developer',
      'Nikita': 'Administrator Assistant'
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <greeting v-bind:persons="persons" v-for="(value,key,index) in persons"></greeting>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

- The template only has access to the props listed, not stuff from the parent scope which is why `index` is not available
- You would bind `:person="value"` since that is the variable that is populated with the current iterated item of `persons`
- Add another prop, 'role', so that you can bind the key of the `person` Object to it

See below:

```js
Vue.component('greeting', {
  template: "<h1>{{person}} is a {{role}}</h1>",
  props: ['person', 'role']
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    persons: {
      'Mike': 'Software Developer',
      'Nikita': 'Administrator Assistant'
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <greeting :person="value" :role="key" v-for="(value, key, index) in persons" :key="index"></greeting>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Your answer has made it very easy for me to understand. I really appreciate it.